# How do I check whether a key was pressed and then do something with the value?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, keypress

I wanted to check if a key was pressed in a form, then perform a subroutine with that key. The code below works only if there are no other controls in the form. What should I do?

```
Private Sub MainForm_KeyPress1(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    MsgBox(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `KeyPreview` property of your form to `True`. This way, you'll catch all the KeyPress events on your form (which will be afterwards handled by the control the keypress happened on, if you didn't set the `Handled` property of the `KeyPressEventArgs` to `True`).

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus. For example, if the KeyPreview property is set
>   to true and the currently selected control is a TextBox, after the
>   keystroke is handled by the event handlers of the form the TextBox
>   control will receive the key that was pressed. To handle keyboard
>   events only at the form level and not allow controls to receive
>   keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your
>   form's KeyPress event handler to true.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx)